# net file for admin drivenet file

Tags: windows-server-2008, powershell

Simple question for you this morning.
I'm currently using the `net file` command in command prompt to obtain the connected user to a drive (F).

I want to know how can I do to get the same information, but with admin connections (F$).

Is it possible with the `net file` command or I could use PowerShell to get this information?

Environment: Windows Server 2008 R2.

Thanks for your time, have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using PSFile from sysinternals?